# Solaris 10 - what is appserv and boot.server? What do they do?

Tags: boot, solaris, binary, application

I'm working in a Solaris 10 zone on legacy startup scripts in the /etc/rc3.d/
There are two items that I don't know what they do. I know how legacy start-up works but just don't know what these items are supposed to do.

```
S16boot.server
S84appserv
```

I'm trying to establish the consequence if I remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a /rplboot directory? Basically, the standard fashion that this particular init script works it to say, "Does /rplboot directory exist? If yes, start rpld." Do a 'ps -ef | grep rpld'; if there's no running process, then there is not issue in removing it. However, I'm not entirely sure why you want to remove it anyway, considering having it there is not really doing anything.

The other utility is to start the Sun Java System Application Server.

I'd recommend removing neither of these, since most likely they are not harming your system in any way whatsoever.